# Completely failing to grasp SoundManager's scope (with examples)

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundmanager2

Apologies for no Fiddle; just trying to understand [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/)'s basics and failing miserably.

**Why doesn't this work:**

```
<script>
soundManager.setup({
  url: 'swf/',
  preferFlash: false,
  onready: function() {
    // Ready to use; soundManager.createSound() etc. can now be called.
  }
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  soundManager.createSound({
    id: 'mySound',
    url: 'audio/sound.mp3',
    autoLoad: true,
    autoPlay: true,
    volume: 50
  });
  mySound.play();
});
</script>
```

**But this does:**

```
<script>
soundManager.setup({
  url: 'swf/',
  preferFlash: false,
  onready: function() {
    soundManager.createSound({
      id: 'mySound',
      url: 'audio/mySound.mp3',
      autoLoad: true,
      autoPlay: true,
      volume: 50
    });
    mySound.play();
  }
});
</script>
```

I don't get it... at all. Does every sound have to be loaded into onready()? And if so, how is that remotely useful for 90% of use cases? I have to be missing something. The [examples they provide](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/api/) make it seem as easy putting this anywhere in my code:

```
soundManager.createSound({
 id: 'mySound2',
 url: 'audio/mySound2.mp3'
});
soundManager.play('mySound2');
```

Yet it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: The API properbly need to do some thing on intialize and before it is ready to run. If you call `createSound` before the API have finished loading there will be a error. Instead of using `$(func..)` as you starting point, you could try using the onready, and call the `$(functio..` from inthere

Comment: How would I use sound objects outside of SM2's own ``onready`` then, if it's not ever properly loaded in time? Are you basically saying I cannot? If so, I really do not get the point of using SM2.

Comment: I have made a **non-working** fiddle of what i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/YdC8j/ -- I have not working with soundmanager I am just guessing

Comment: Thanks. Add it as an answer and I'll give it to you. Basically, from what I gather, unless you build your application with SM2 in mind, it's just not worth the effort. I'm pretty disappointed after everyone talked it up so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments

The API properbly need to do some thing on intialize and before it is ready to run. If you call createSound before the API have finished loading there will be a error. Instead of using `$(func..)` as you starting point, you could try using the onready, and call the `$(functio..` from inthere

I have made a non-working fiddle of what i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/YdC8j -- I have not working with soundmanager I am just guessing